# NSIS to get the last string of the file path

Tags: nsis

How to get only the jre1.8.0_91 from the string in NSIS language?

```
String "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Vinod Hopefully you are using the latest version of NSIS. Also, include either the latest version of headers with NSIS (nsh.zip), or include the WordFind function

```
!include "WordFunc.nsh"
```

in your .nsi script.

With that you can use the WordFind function to extract the file name (jre1.8.0_91 in your example) from the file path (C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91 in your example) like this:

```
 ${WordFind} "${FilePath}" "\" "-1" $R0
```

$R0 will contain the last "word" (jre1.8.0_91) from the file path.

This was accomplished by using the backslash ("\") as the delimiter of the string, and selecting the first word, counting backwards ("-1") from the end of the string.

Comment: Ideally you should look for both \ and / as the path separator.

Answer (score 0):

Every string operation in NSIS can be coded with `StrCpy`, `StrCmp` and `StrLen`. You can try something like this:

```
!macro PathGetFilename path outvar
Push "${path}"
Call PathGetFilename
Pop ${outvar}
!macroend
Function PathGetFilename
Exch $1
Push $2
Push $3
StrCpy $2 ""
loop:
    IntOp $2 $2 - 1
    StrCpy $0 $1 1 $2
    StrCmp $0 "" done
    StrCmp $0 '\' +3
    StrCmp $0 '/' +2
    Goto loop
    IntOp $2 $2 + 1
    IntCmp $2 0 "" +2 +2
        StrCpy $1 "" ; Ended with slash, return empty string
    StrCpy $1 $1 "" $2
done:
Pop $3
Pop $2
Exch $1
FunctionEnd


Section
!insertmacro PathGetFilename "c:\test" $0
DetailPrint |$0|
!insertmacro PathGetFilename "c:\foo/bar" $0
DetailPrint |$0|
!insertmacro PathGetFilename "nameonly" $0
DetailPrint |$0|
!insertmacro PathGetFilename "\endslash\" $0
DetailPrint |$0|
SectionEnd
```